# React Google Maps: display Markers on MapWithADirectionRenderer recompose Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, recompose

I have my component *MapWithADirectionsRenderer* defined like [here](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer)

```
var markers = [];
const MapWithADirectionsRenderer = compose(

withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?...",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }}/>
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  lifecycle({

  componentDidMount() {

  const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  DirectionsService.route({
    origin: this.props.origin,
    destination: this.props.destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  }, (result, status) => {

    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      // here I fill my marker array correctly

      this.setState({
          directions: result
      });

     } else {
      console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
     }
   });
 }

 })
)(props=> 
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={// coordinates}
  >
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer 
                            options={{draggable:true}}
                            directions={props.directions}
                            ref={(r) => directionsRef = r}
                            onDirectionsChanged={getDirections}
                             />
    }
    {markers.map( (marker,i) => (
                              <Marker
                                key={i}
                                position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
                            >
                              </Marker>
                          ))}


  </GoogleMap>
);
```

but after moving route on map, the directions fetched from Google update correctly, but not the markers that I want to show. The same markers are always shown.

Is there some way to update *MapWithADirectionRenderer* so it re-render my Markers and not only the directions? Thank you

Comment: Where is the markers array defined? I would expect it to be part of props. ComponentDidMount only fires once, so if it's a value that's dependent on props it will not updated after the initial mounting of the component.

Comment: It is defined outside, before starting defining MapWithADirectionRenderer component, but is filled with lat,lng inside componentDidMount() function. I tried to define it inside and access it by props but I get 'map' of undefined error. @Shadowfool

Comment: I'd have to see what you're doing in componentDidMount for this to make sense, but none the less that's not going to update as props update since it only fires once.

Comment: You can see now @Shadowfool